# Dimensionality / noise reduction techniques for regression problems

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

What are some techniques for dimensionality reduction in regression problems? I have tried the only unsupervised techniques I know, PCA and Kernel PCA (using the scikit learn library), but I have not seen any improvements using these. Perhaps these are only suitable for classification problems? What are some other techniques I can try? Preferably, ones that are implemented in sklearn.

Comment: dimensonality reduction is not something that should improve results. It will only do that, if the following model (regressor) is weak enough to be "distracted" by correlated inputs etc. consequently this is not something you are supposed to use when building models, unless this is clear that your model fails due to too many dimensions (and you do not want to change the model). In general, you should rather build a stronger regressor instead of doing independent, information losing, dimensionality reduction.

Comment: what if the data itself is very noisy?

Comment: still it is better to have a stronger regressor, as you will try to do both - cancel noise and build model **jointly**. Dimensonality reduction splits your problem to two independent parts, thus has to be weaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very general question, and the suitability of the techniques (or combinations of them), really depends on your problem specifics.

In general, there are several categories of dimension reduction (asides from those you mentioned.

1. Perhaps the simplest form of dimension reduction is to just use some of the features, in which case we are really talking about feature selection (see [sklearn's module](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)).
2. Another way would be to cluster ([sklearn's](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)), and replace each cluster by an aggregate of its components.
3. Finally, some regressors use l1 penalization and properties of convex optimization to simultaneously select a subset of features; in sklearn, see [the lasso and elastic net](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html).

Once again, this a very broad problem. There are entire books and competitions even of feature selection, which is a subset of dimension reduction.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of feature projection / transformation, rather than feature selection ( the dataset only has around 20 features, but the data is very noisy)

Comment: @SimonZhu In that case, the only other thing that comes to mind in sklearn is [random projections](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/random_projection.html).

Comment: @SimonZhu Another thing - as I wrote, feature selection is a special case of dimension reduction. It doesn't matter if 20 is a large or small number absolutely. There's always the possibility that a subset of the features is the best for your predictor.

Comment: I see, I shall look into that a bit more (thing is, it is really only 5 features, but one of them is discrete with 20 unique values, so I have one hot encoded that one, so in the end I get "24" features)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @AmiTavory 's good answer:  `PCA` principal components analysis can be used here.  If you do not wish to perform `dimensionality reduction` simply retain the same number of eigenvectors from the `PCA` as the size of the input matrix: in your case 20.

The resulting output will be orthogonal eigenvectors: you may consider them to provide the "transformation" you are seeking as follow: the vectors are ranked by their respective amount of variance they represent wrt the inputs.